# What is the function of "skip" object in knockout mapping object "create" function

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

The [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) of KO mapping plugin specify following two objects in "options" parameter passed to the "create" function. Looking at the actual object, there is another "skip" object. **Is it something internal or can this be used somehow if we don't want to create any object?**

> data: The JavaScript object containing the data for this child
>
> parent: The parent object or array to which this child belongs

**What is the best way to skip the creation of a complete object?** Currently I return null from the create function and do something like:

```
var mapping = {
  'create': function(options){
     // if I dont want to create
     return null;
     // else
     return new MyObject();
   }
}
var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
mapped.remove(null)
```

Comment: in one word "ignore" http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#ignoring_certain_properties_using_ignore

Comment: ignore only skips certain properties to be ignored from mapping. I want to ignore the complete object.